# Child window disappears on scrolling

Tags: c++, visual-c++, credential-providers

```
HWND hwndDlg=GetDesktopWindow();
HWND hImage=CreateWindow(_T("STATIC"),  _T(""), SS_CENTERIMAGE | SS_REALSIZEIMAGE | SS_BITMAP | WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
        550, 480, 10, 10, hwndDlg, NULL,
        (HINSTANCE)GetWindowLong(hwndDlg, GWLP_HINSTANCE),
        NULL); 
LPWSTR imgPath = getImagePath();    
HBITMAP bitmap = (HBITMAP)LoadImageW(NULL,imgPath, IMAGE_BITMAP,0,0,LR_LOADFROMFILE);
SendMessage(hImage, STM_SETIMAGE,  (WPARAM)IMAGE_BITMAP, (LPARAM)bitmap);
```

With this piece of code i'm able to create a child window to the current window and make a picture appear on that window. It works as expected. But my problem is when i scroll the child window and the picture disappear. What am I doing wrong? I'm totally new with windows programming. Please help me out.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VO0uD.png

You may see the screenschot in the above link

Comment: The STM_SETIMAGE message is only documented to work correctly with 4 types of static controls see remarks in: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb760782(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I agree with Richard. You are better off registering and painting your own window class.

Comment: I some how kinda solved my problem, but I get another problem.. When I scroll, image stays, but it is not moving. I want it to move up and down as I scroll. Any ideas?